# Finding the average, the five smallest, and the five largest numbers in an array

Tags: php, beginner, programming-challenge, array

I am going though some PHP arrays exercises on [w3resource](http://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/php-array-exercises.php). I have just completed the following:

> 9. Write a PHP script to calculate and display average temperature, five lowest and highest temperatures.
>
> Recorded temperatures : `78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 75, 76, 73, 68, 62, 73, 72, 65, 74, 62, 62, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    
    $temperatures = array(78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 75, 76, 73, 68, 62, 73, 72, 65, 74, 62, 62, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73);
    
    function listvalues($value)
    {
        echo "$value, ";
    }
    
    function printAverage($array)
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach($array as $element)
        {
            $total += $element;
        }
        echo number_format($total / count($array), 1);
    }
    
    echo "Recorded temperatures : ";
    array_walk($temperatures, "listvalues");
    echo "<br>";
    
    echo "Average Temperature is : ";
    printAverage($temperatures);
    echo "<br>";
    
    //sort the temperatures in ascending order for both of the following lists.
    sort($temperatures);
    
    //print the first 5 values
    echo "List of five lowest temperatures : ";
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        echo "$temperatures[$i], ";
    }
    echo "<br>"; 
    
    //print the last 5 values
    echo "List of five highest temperatures : ";       
    for($i = count($temperatures) - 5; $i <= count($temperatures) - 1; $i++)
    {
        echo "$temperatures[$i], ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

And here is its output:

> ```
> Recorded temperatures : 78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 75, 76, 73, 68, 62, 73, 72, 65, 74, 62, 62, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73, 
> Average Temperature is : 69.8
> List of seven lowest temperatures : 60, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
> List of seven highest temperatures : 76, 76, 78, 79, 85,
> ```

(I paid no attention to fixing the commas at the end of each part of the output, for now.)

My questions are:

- Is this an appropriate use of `array_walk()`? Is it more appropriate to use a  `foreach()` loop?
- Is `($total / count($array)` the easiest way to find the average of an array, and is that the best way to format it for readability?
- Can you spot parts of my code which you think could be coded better?

Comment: Your input is fixed, so you don't need to check for empty arrays. In the general case, you might divide by zero. Just saying.

Comment: Interesting how the output says "List of seven...", I would have expected "List of five..." there. :-)

Comment: @marcvangend Indeed; there are many similar mistakes/typos on the other examples. I do my best to ignore them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of built-in functions in PHP that would make your code shorter and more direct.

The first is [`implode`](http://php.net/IMPLODE). `implode` takes and optional glue string and an array of values, and joins them together into a single string. So for `implode(", ", array(1, "a", 3))`, it would return `"1, a, 3"`. This avoids the need to loop over the elements of an array to print them with a separator, and to catch the last case where there should be no separator.

The second is [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php). This, as its name suggests, takes an array and sums the values. This also avoids an explicit loop.

The third is [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). This function will take an array, and return a portion of it based on the given parameters. It can even be used to index in reverse with a negative offset.

Putting it all together, we get the following:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";

    $temperatures = array(78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 75, 76, 73, 68, 62, 73, 72, 65, 74, 62, 62, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73);

    echo "Recorded temperatures : ";
    echo implode(", ", $temperatures);
    echo "<br>";

    echo "Average Temperature is : ";
    echo number_format(array_sum($temperatures) / count($temperatures), 1);
    echo "<br>";

    //sort the temperatures in ascending order for both of the following lists.
    sort($temperatures);

    //print the first 5 values
    echo "List of five lowest temperatures : ";
    echo implode(", ", array_slice($temperatures, 0, 5));
    echo "<br>"; 

    //print the last 5 values
    echo "List of five highest temperatures : ";
    echo implode(", ", array_slice($temperatures, -5, 5));
    echo "<br>";

    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for this, I mentioned your answer in my blog if that's ok.

Comment: @alanbuchanan That's absolutely fine. I'm just glad my answer helped. :)

Answer (score 6):

> Is it more appropriate to use a  foreach() loop?

You're right. `foreach` loop would be more appropriate.
Use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) only when you need to

> Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

This is not the case.

> Is ($total / count($array) the easiest way to find the average of an array

Since the average mathematics is `total_items / number_items`, then yes.

> Can you spot parts of my code which you think could be coded better?

The piece of code

```
for($i = count($temperatures) - 5; $i <= count($temperatures) - 1; $i++)
```

could be rewritten like this:

```
for($i = count($temperatures) - 5, $t=count($temperatures) - 1; $i <= $t; $i++)
```

In this way `count($temperatures) - 1` is not performed all the time, only at the beginning of the loop. Documentation: [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know PHP, so this won't be a comprehensive review.  However, this `for` statement really jumps out at me:

```
for($i = count($temperatures) - 5; $i <= count($temperatures) - 1; $i++)
```

You can write that more simply as:

```
for($i = count($temperatures) - 5; $i < count($temperatures); $i++)
```

Comment: Since `count` is a function, and it has to iterate over the array to count the values, it is advised to store the result of `count` inside a variable. Each function has aditional overhead when called. You could do `for($length = count($temperatures), $i = $length - 5; $i < $length; $i++);`, reducing it to only 1 iteration instead of ... many...